# In SOLR, how do I mention that starting character should not be altered?

Tags: solr

I have a use case where fuzzy search needs to be applied.

Max number of characters in my field is 10. I don't want first three letters to be altered while applying fuzzy search.

For example, I want to keep first two letters not to be changed.

```
alpha 
alpine
alkine
```

I want `alpah` to match but not `clpha`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You could index two fields - one with the first three letters and one with `[3:]`. Apply an exact `fq` against the first field and a fuzzy search with the remaining search string against the second field?

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh I think its the only way.